# Is this the current repositories for Precise?

Tags: 12.04, updates, repository

I've googled this for hours and can't seem to locate an official repository that responds...

```
## main & restricted repositories
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted

## universe repositories
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are unsure which are the right repos, I recommend you to generate a new list.

Go to this [website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and choose your country and language and with repos you want. If you don't know what they mean you can read the description of every repo there.

After generating the list, copy the whole output into your `/etc/sources.list`, **BUT** make a backup of the original one first.

Then you habe to run `sudo apt-get update` to renew the package list.